# JQUERY Touch Screen Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, safari

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">         
    <textarea id="keyboard"></textarea><Input type="button" id="butPress" value="Display Keyboard"></input>
</div>
```

There is 2 main controls at my web page.
One is TextBox and other is Button.
When i press the button i want to display Keyboard so that any tablet pc can type without using physical keyboard.

It will be better if you can give me any code which is compatible with Apple safari browser.

Let me get suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great tutorial on making a jquery keyboard:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery/

You can then write a small bit of jQuery like this (set the keyboard div to have a style of display:none in the css):

```
$('.button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $('.keyboard').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Just have the button put keyboard focus on the textbox, any modern device should bring up the keyboard automatically. Don't make your own keyboard.

Comment: I think he means on Tablet PCs, which have both a physical keyboard and a touch screen